# Correct database after backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need some help with a query. Actually we have some wrongs DATA in our database.

For some technical reason I restore the backup in another schema.

So actually in my Schema1.DB1.TBL1 I got the backed up DATA and in my Schema2.DB2.TBL2 I have the same table but with some wrongs DATA.

Could you please tell me an SQL query which can help me to restore my data?

```
UPDATE Schema1.DB1.TBL1 
SET 
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column1= Schema2.DB2.TBL2.column1 , 
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column2= Schema2.DB2.TBL.column2 , 
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column3= Schema2.DB2.TBL.column3 , 
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column4= Schema2.DB2.TBL.column4 ,
     .....
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column100= Schema2.DB2.TBL.column100 
FROM Schema1.DB1.TBL1
JOIN Schema2.DB2.TBL on (Schema1.DB1.TBL1.id= Schema2.DB2.TBL.id)
```

The problem is I have to many columns. So I'm asking you if there is an easier way?

Comment: If you want to perform an `UPDATE` then you need to define *all* the columns you want to `UPDATE`. There is not short hand syntax like SET TBL1 * = TBL.*`.

Comment: Also, that naming structure is *very* odd. Do you *really* have a database called `Schema1`, with a schema called `DB1`? Also [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: cant you just restore complete table ?

Comment: is it a way to create a script with all talbe datas?
actually i can restore a table yes but how?
And no my tables are not named like that it's for the explication

Comment: _So I'm asking you if there is an easier way_ The answer to that is relative. Given that you find typing all the column names (how many - really?) too much work, the other option is to use dynamic sql to query the meta-data of the tables, generate the appropriate queries, and then execute them. You replace one form of tedious but relatively "easy" work with a much more complicated process of writing and testing dynamic sql - something that likely requires more skill than you have. SSMS has ways of providing column lists - perhaps that is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the answers are multiples there is some way to do it :

```
/*way 1*/
delete from schema1.db1.tbl
select * into schema1.db1.tbl from schema2.db2.tb2

--or do the same with a truncate
/*way 2*/
delete from schema1.db1.tbl
UPDATE Schema1.DB1.TBL1 
SET 
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column1= Schema2.DB2.TBL2.column1 , 
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column2= Schema2.DB2.TBL.column2 , 
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column3= Schema2.DB2.TBL.column3 , 
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column4= Schema2.DB2.TBL.column4 ,
     .....
     Schema1.DB1.TBL1.column100= Schema2.DB2.TBL.column100 
FROM Schema1.DB1.TBL1
JOIN Schema2.DB2.TBL on (Schema1.DB1.TBL1.id= Schema2.DB2.TBL.id)
```

thanks for your answers as I said, I didn't know if there is a "right way" to do that.

And definitly I'm sure there are other ways to do that. but it if could help someone.